# Browser version dimension missing in GA4 API

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

There is no “Browser version” dimension in the GA4 API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#dimensions

Also it is not found in the Reports section of the Analytics console:
[image: Reports section]

Whereas in the [support article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9164320?hl=en#:%7E:text=As%20part%20of%20this%20change%2C%20clients%20will%20no%20longer%20know%20the%20exact%20subversion%20of%20Chrome%20in%20Google%20Analytics%20but%20will%20still%20know%20the%20browser%20and%20major%20version%20number.) it is said:

> As part of this change, clients will no longer know the exact subversion of Chrome in Google Analytics but will still **know the browser and major version number**.

**Where is it in the console?**

Interestingly, in the [exploration area](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7579450?hl=en) this dimension is present:
[image: Exploration section]

Secondary question is: How to explain this imparity and how to get this dimension in the API/Reports?

Comment: You understand that this is a beta api right?

Comment: Of course, but this dimension is missing in the reports as well, despite the fact that GA4 itself is the [default for new properties since Oct 14, 2020](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9164320?hl=en#:~:text=As%20of%20October%2014%2C%202020%2C%20a%20Google%20Analytics%204%20property%20(formerly%20known%20as%20an%20%22App%20%2B%20Web%22%20property)%20is%20now%20the%20default%20when%20you%20create%20a%20new%20property). Anyhow, the accepted answer confirms that this is by design.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Browser version dimension is not available in Reports, is not available in the GA4 Data API ([API schema](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#dimensions)). **However, it is available in explorations** (Sidebar > Explore).

Some infrequently used and/or high cardinality dimensions are available in explorations, not available in Reports, and not available in the API. Browser version is infrequently used.

Thanks, Brett

The Google Analytics Team

Comment: Thank you very much! It was so important to get an authoritative answer explaining this imparity between exploration and reports/API.

Comment: It's been 15 months and it's still not available...

Comment: Is this to suggest... it's not coming?

Comment: I really need to know the browser versions, as you have to now what versions you have to support on your website, this highly depends on the clientele. So why has this been dropped? GA4 is so much worse than GA

Comment: @basZero to be fair, it has not been dropped, it's just only available in Exploration (as stated in Brett's post above) and not the main Reports.  I agree it's pretty annoying, can't think why they would do it this way.  I do find explorations more tedious to put together, but they can be very powerful once you figure out how to define the Segment, Dimensions and Metrics.